# «Нет нигде» или «нет везде» — разные смыслы?

Tags: грамотная-речь, наречия

По ощущениям, привычнее сказать "нет нигде". Но является ли ошибкой сказать иначе, другой ли при этом будет смысл? Может, двойное отрицание  играет роль категоричного усиления или типа того?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Нет везде"* не говорят. Так уж сложилось, что в русском языке в данном случае используется двойное отрицание. Одинарное может быть только таким, например:

> *Везде искал, но так и не нашёл его.*

Answer (score 1):

"Везде" в силу его значения сложно употребить с "нет". Везде = во всех местах (одновременно). От  ст.-слав. вьсь (весь) + наречный суф. -де. То есть, логически, не может такого быть, чтобы быть одновременно во всех местах, но в этом/каком-то месте не быть (тогда получается, что не во всех, и это парадокс).

*Везде нет домов. = Во всех (без исключения) местах нет домов.

Частица "ни" в слове "нигде" не столько отрицательная, сколько усилительная. Нигде  = ни в одном месте. И обычно "ни" подразумевает последующее отрицание "не(т)".

Ср. *"Никто знал" и "Никто не знал".
       *"Ни зги видно" и "Ни зги не видно".

Answer (score 1):

Всё-таки комбинация "везде" и "нет" возможна:
*Везде, где искал, [его] нет.* || За счёт придаточного, которое уточняет слишком общее слово "везде".
*Везде по округе нет света.* || Везде отсутствует свет. "По округе" сужает значение местоимения.

То есть необходимо уточнение, сужающее понятие "везде".

Результат этих фраз одинаковый, но подход разный:
нигде нет — отсутствует место локации;
везде нет — во всех местах нет. || Необходимо уточнить, где именно "везде".

Comment: Поддержу ответ, хотя ему не помешали бы подтверждающие цитаты хороших писателей. Например: "Везде теснота, везде нет желанного ему приволья". И не всегда требуется уточнять, где именно "везде".